# Adding counter/index to a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists of strings:

```
listBefore = [['4', '5', '1', '1'],
              ['4', '6', '1', '1'],
              ['4', '7', '8', '1'],
              ['1', '2', '1', '1'],
              ['2', '3', '1', '1'],
              ['7', '8', '1', '1'],
              ['7', '9', '1', '1'],
              ['2', '4', '3', '1']]
```

and I would like to add a counter/index in the middle of each list so that the list looks like:

```
listAfter = [['4', '5', '1', '1', '1'],
             ['4', '6', '2', '1', '1'],
             ['4', '7', '3', '8', '1'],
             ['1', '2', '4', '1', '1'],
             ['2', '3', '5', '1', '1'],
             ['7', '8', '6', '1', '1'],
             ['7', '9', '7', '1', '1'],
             ['2', '4', '8', '3', '1']]
```

What would be the easiest way to do so? I could probably loop over the lists and add the index, but is there a cleaner way to do so?

Cheers,
Kate

Edit:
The code I wrote works for me:

```
item = 1
for list in listBefore:
    list.insert(2,str(item))
    item = item + 1
print listBefore
```

I was wondering if there is another way to do so more efficiently or in one step.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I agree you should try writing some yourself and see what works. For some help, check out `enumerate`.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the parent list with `enumerate()` to get counter (used as `i` in the below example) along with list element. In the sublist, insert the `i` at the middle of sublist using `list.insert(index, value)` method.
*Note:* The value of counter i.e. `i` will be of `int` type, so you have to explicitly type cast it to `str` as `str(i)`before inserting. Below is the sample code:

```
for i, sub_list in enumerate(my_list, 1):  # Here my_list is the list mentioned in question as 'listBefore'
    sub_list.insert(len(sub_list)/2, str(i))

# Value of 'my_list'
# [['4', '5', '1', '1', '1'], 
#  ['4', '6', '2', '1', '1'], 
#  ['4', '7', '3', '8', '1'],
#  ['1', '2', '4', '1', '1'], 
#  ['2', '3', '5', '1', '1'], 
#  ['7', '8', '6', '1', '1'], 
#  ['7', '9', '7', '1', '1'], 
#  ['2', '4', '8', '3', '1']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform this with a list comprehension

```
listAfter = [listBefore[i][:len(listBefore[i])/2] + [str(i+1)] + listBefore[i][len(listBefore[i])/2:] for i in range(len(listBefore))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about `enumerate`, it lets you iterate over the list with two iterators - one (`str_list` in this case`) holds the current item in the list, and the other (`i`) holds it's index in the list.

```
for i,str_list in enumerate(listBefore):
  listBefore[i] = str_list[:len(str_list)//2] + [str(i+1)] + str_list[len(str_list)//2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> data = [['4', '5', '1', '1'],
            ['4', '6', '1', '1'],
            ['4', '7', '8', '1'],
            ['1', '2', '1', '1'],
            ['2', '3', '1', '1'],
            ['7', '8', '1', '1'],
            ['7', '9', '1', '1'],
            ['2', '4', '3', '1']]
>>> print [row[:len(row)//2] + [str(i)] + row[len(row)//2:]
           for i, row in enumerate(data, start=1)]
[['4', '5', '1', '1', '1'],
 ['4', '6', '2', '1', '1'],
 ['4', '7', '3', '8', '1'],
 ['1', '2', '4', '1', '1'],
 ['2', '3', '5', '1', '1'],
 ['7', '8', '6', '1', '1'],
 ['7', '9', '7', '1', '1'],
 ['2', '4', '8', '3', '1']]
```